# Pagination is broken and I need help fixing it

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination

I am having an issue with pagination on a site I am working on. The client noticed that on her category pages, the pagination does not function after `page 1`. What I mean is that on `pages 2` and onwards the posts no longer display from the WordPress loop. I was just wondering why this was and how I can fix it?

Here is my template page code for the category pages:

```
<?php
get_header();?>
<div class="section blog">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                <div class="share">
                        <span>Share:</span>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                </div>
                        <?php

                            $link = $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
                            $link_array = explode('/',$link);
                            $page = $link_array[count($link_array)-2];

                            $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

                            $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'posts_per_page' => 4,
                            'paged' => $paged,
                            'category_name' => $page
                            );

                            $post_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                            if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
                                while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
                                    $post_query->the_post();
                                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
                                    if($image[0] == ''){
                                        $image[0] = get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/placeholder-blog.jpg';
                                    }
                        ?>

                <article>
                    <div class="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                                <div class="head">  
                                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                    <span><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> by <?php echo get_the_author(); ?> | <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Leave a Comment</a></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 feature-image">
                                <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
                                <p><?php $content = get_the_content(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 400, '...'); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                                <div class="category">
                                    <p>
                                        Filed Under: 
                                        <?php
                                            $category = get_the_category();
                                            foreach($category as $key=>$cat){
                                                echo '<a href="' . get_site_url() . '/blog/' . $cat->slug . '">' . $cat->name . '</a>';
                                                if(($key+1) != count($category)){
                                                    echo ', ';
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <hr>
                        <?php
                                }
                            }
                        ?>


                        <div class="section nav text-center">
                            <!-- pagination here -->
                            <?php
                                if (function_exists(custom_pagination)) {
                                custom_pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
                                }
                            ?>

                        </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <?php include('inc/sidebar.php'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php 
include('inc/connect.php');
get_footer(); 
?>
```

There is also a custom function built into functions.php for pagination that perhaps contains as issue as well:

```
function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='') {

  if (empty($pagerange)) {
    $pagerange = 2;
  }

  /**
   * This first part of our function is a fallback
   * for custom pagination inside a regular loop that
   * uses the global $paged and global $wp_query variables.
   * 
   * It's good because we can now override default pagination
   * in our theme, and use this function in default quries
   * and custom queries.
   */
  global $paged;
  if (empty($paged)) {
    $paged = 1;
  }
  if ($numpages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if(!$numpages) {
        $numpages = 1;
    }
  }

  /** 
   * We construct the pagination arguments to enter into our paginate_links
   * function. 
   */
  $pagination_args = array(
    'base'            => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
    'format'          => 'page/%#%',
    'total'           => $numpages,
    'current'         => $paged,
    'show_all'        => False,
    'end_size'        => 1,
    'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
    'prev_next'       => True,
    'prev_text'       => __('<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>'),
    'next_text'       => __('<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'),
    'type'            => 'plain',
    'add_args'        => false,
    'add_fragment'    => ''
  );

  $paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

  if ($paginate_links) {
    echo "<nav class='custom-pagination'>";
      echo $paginate_links;
    echo "</nav>";
  }

}
```

Here are live examples of such:

```
https://www.staceybarr.com/measure-up/category/podcast/page/2/
https://www.staceybarr.com/measure-up/category/podcast/page/1/
```

Everything looks correct to me but alas there is still an issue, I was just wondering if I could get some help with this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the first page works but the second doesn't, though this may be a hint toward the problem. Toward the bottom of the category template page you have the following:

```
if (function_exists(custom_pagination)) {
    custom_pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
}
```

If you review the above, there is a variable called `$custom_query`. This looks like it's a WordPress query that should be able to have a max_numb_pages item inside it. The issue is `$custom_query` doesn't exist anywhere else on the page and doesn't appear to be global. You should change it to reflect your query on the page, `$post_query`. The updated code would look like this:

```
if (function_exists(custom_pagination)) {
    custom_pagination($post_query->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
}
```

This should tell the pagination that there are a number of pages and possibly render the correct link.

Further, I would recommend you `print_r` the output of `$link`, `$link_array`, `$page`, and `$paged` to determine if all of those variables are outputting the correct response.

```
$link = $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$link_array = explode('/',$link);
$page = $link_array[count($link_array)-2];

$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 4,
'paged' => $paged,
'category_name' => $page
);

print_r($link);
print_r($link_array);
print_r($page);
print_r($paged);
print_r($args);
```

In the case of `$args`, make sure it's telling WordPress the correct page in the `paged` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!
When I change the $custom_query to $post_query, it starts to act funny and the pagination displays an incorrect number of page links. For example if they are 2 pages, it will display 5 pages with $post_query. I used the print_r and the variables are outputting the correct responses. It still has the same issue with posts not being displayed after the first page how ever!

Comment: I spoke too soon Tom; I noticed that on page 2+ of any category pages the category name will change from what it is, to "2", "3", etc. depending on what page you are on.
For example on: https://www.staceybarr.com/measure-up/category/podcast/, it renders: `code`www.staceybarr.com/measure-up/category/podcast/Array ( [0] => www.staceybarr.com [1] => measure-up [2] => category [3] => podcast [4] => ) podcast1Array ( [post_type] => post [posts_per_page] => 4 [paged] => 1 [category_name] => podcast )`code`

Comment: While on https://www.staceybarr.com/measure-up/category/podcast/page/2/, it renders: `code`www.staceybarr.com/measure-up/category/podcast/page/2/Array ( [0] => www.staceybarr.com [1] => measure-up [2] => category [3] => podcast [4] => page [5] => 2 [6] => ) 22Array ( [post_type] => post [posts_per_page] => 4 [paged] => 2 [category_name] => 2 )`code` I was just wondering what I could do to correct the mismatched category names

Comment: @NeoLobster Category name is coming from the $page variable, which is attempting to pull from the URL broken into an array with $link_array. If you notice, the array key for category is always 3, so you may want to change $page in the $args from what it is to $link_array[3] and see if that works.

Comment: @NeoLobster Unsure why your category template is set up like this also - this isn't how it works with a normal configuration. It may be the way the taxonomy/post type is set up, but since it's like this I'd try what I posted above.

Comment: Thanks so much Tom!
When I changed the value of $page to be $link_array[3] the pagination started to work perfectly!
I very much appreciated all of your help!

Comment: @NeoLobster Not a problem at all, happy it worked!